# Is there a way to exclude a word or a speech in regular expressions?

Tags: java, regex, netbeans

I've a to match with a regular expression a text like this:

```
====================
    DO NOT ALTER OR REMOVE COPYRIGHT NOTICES OR THIS HEADER.

    Copyright 2008-2009 Company, Inc. All rights reserved.


    The contents of this file are subject to the terms of the Common Development
    and Distribution License("CDDL") (the "License"). You may not use this file
    except in compliance with the License.

    You can obtain a copy of the License at https://oss.oracle.com/licenses/CDDL
    See the License for the specific language governing permissions and limitations
    under the License.

    When distributing the Covered Code, include this CDDL Header Notice in each file
    and include the License file at https://oss.oracle.com/licenses/CDDL.
    If applicable, add the following below this CDDL Header, with the fields
    enclosed by brackets [] replaced by your own identifying information:
    "Portions Copyrighted [year] [name of copyright owner]"
    ====================

    Copyright 2011-2013 Company. All rights reserved.
```

and the portion between =========== is static never changes, so I could search for this expression in a static way, but it is NOT a well formed regular expression, how can I make all text between =========== static in a regular expression?

Comment: That entirely depends on the programming language you're using. Which one is it?

Comment: Maybe in basic regex format: `\={22}[^\=]*\={22}`?

Comment: If the text is static, don't use regex but strict equality.

Comment: Also, I don't want to question your motives, but regular expressions are best when *not* used on static text. Are you sure you want a regex?

Comment: It could seem a bit strange, but I'm trying to do this search with regular expression finder of Netbeans. @H2CO3 what does it means 22?

Comment: Yes I'm sure I want a regex because I've also variable text lines like last line and other initial (omitted) lines and I've to match them with a regex. I've to match whole text not only search for static part of text

Comment: so I need to bind static part of text with a regex

Comment: @andPat Maybe I just counted the wrong number of equal signs, but they're approx. 22.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can't actually write code, but only a regular expression, you can turn off all meta-characters for a certain part of your pattern with `\Q` and `\E`:

```
startOfRegex\Q============...\EendOfRegex
```

This way, the part between `\Q` and `\E` can contain arbitrary regex meta-characters (like patrentheses, and brackets and asterisks and backslashes and whatnot), while `startOfRegex` and `endOfRegex` can be normal and arbitrary regex patterns.

You only get problems if the string contains `\E` or ends with a backslash. In that case, Tim Pietzker's `Pattern.quote` is the only general way to go.

Answer (score 3):

Netbeans uses Java, right? Then you can use

```
String regex = Pattern.quote(my_verbatim_string);
```

to properly escape all regex metacharacters.

But in all likelihood, it would be a much better idea to use a regex like `(?s)={20}.*?={20}` to find all the text between `====================`s, and then do a strict equality comparison.

Comment: so there isn't a way to say: ok all text (whatever charachter) between  "these two tags" is static part of regexp and don't parse as regexp, right?

Comment: @andPat that's exactly what `Pattern.quote` does.

Comment: ahh thanks I didn't know, but I don't have to use Java, I've only to write a regular expression, in other words I've to "quote" by hand static text because I've to pass this regular expression to an evaluator which takes in input only pure regexps.

Comment: @andPat see my answer then. Java and some other flavors support `\Q...\E` for literal parts in a regex.

Comment: I use Netbeans only for testing purpose, to check if my regexp is correct. Because I make the search on header of java files Netbeans is the best way to see if my regexp matches with them or not.